# PHP after image loaded from directory - wrong orientation

Tags: php, image, file, orientation, landscape-portrait

Actually i'm using a simple PHP snippet to iterate through a directory to grab images and insert them into the html markup.

Now im facing the problem that all images are oriented in landscape. So also portrait images are oriented as landscape images.

Here's my snippet:

```
    <?php 
    $projectpath = 'Projects';
    $projects = glob($projectpath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($projects as $key=>$value): ?>
        <section class="project">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="project-images">
                            <?php 
                                $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/'.$value);
                                while($file = readdir($handle)){                                        
                                    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                                        echo '<img class="img-responsive" alt="'. $file .'" src="'. $value .'/'. $file .'"/>';
                                    }
                                }                                                                    
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So what do i'm missing here? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could just create some CSS that rotates the photo 90 Degrees

Comment: Hmm how can css verify the orientation ?

Comment: Well i assume your landscape images their width value is larger than their height value, and for portrait images it is the other way around, so checking which one is larger and decide by that if it has to turn or not.

Comment: Ok so we talking about javascript or jquery :)

Comment: I would use PHP for that, check the getimagesize() function in the documentation, create an if else statement with that and you're good to go.

Comment: i'll write you an example, give me a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt those images really have different orientations. More likely *all* images are in landscape layout (greater width than height), so the visualization is correct from a technical point of view.

I guess you usually look at the images with some viewer on your PC which auto rotates the images based on some orientation flag stored inside the images meta data. But such flag does *not* change the real, technical orientation (or better resolution). Instead such flag is only a hint for visualization of the images. Your project does not consult that flag, that is why your images *appear* to be rotated, whilst in reality they are not.

So the solution is one of two options:

1. rotate the images prior to using them inside your project, so that their real, technical orientation is correct and the images only have to be displayed without any additional rotation.
2. use js or php or whatever to detect that orientation flag and evaluate it. Based on the outcome you can set some css class which results in a css based rotation of those images that need to be rotated for visualization.

Comment: The orientations are different... Checked through the meta informations. This was my first approach.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no instance in a web application that automatically / automagically rotates images. If those images _really_ had different orientations they would be displayed in different orientations. There is something you are missing here. How did you check the orientation? What tool did you use?

Comment: Actually the above comment is only valid if you do not (accidentally) rotate the images yourself by some css rule or the like. Check all those css classes and their effect inside the browser. :-)

Comment: You are right! It was an orientation issue. I checked it again with photoshop and orientation was the same! I only had to rotate it in photoshop and now its working perfectly! thank you

Comment: Great you solved it! A general hint: when trying to find out the _real_ technical details like in this situation it always is better to use simple-to-the-bone command line utilities instead of some fancy graphical utility. Those are comfortable for normal tasks, but they never show you the real world, but always their own interpretation which often leads to wrong impressions :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple PHP example to check if the image is portrait or landscape:

```
<?php

$imagePath = 'images/imagename.png';
$imageSize = getimagesize($imagePath); //returns an array
$imageWidth = $imageSize[0]; // array key 0 is width
$imageHeight = $imageSize[1]; // array key 1 is height

if($imageWidth < $imageHeight){
    echo '<img class="ROTATE">'//add the rotate class
} elseif($imageWidth > $imageHeight){
    echo '<img>'//do not add the rotate class
} else {
    echo '<img>'//do not add the rotate class
?>
```

Take in mind that this is only an example and that you'll have to tweak the script to work properly for you.

Comment: And if the image has a square size? :-) _Always_ provide a default/else case!

Comment: Thanks for adding the `else` case. But actually you could simply remove the `elseif` case ... :-)

Comment: True, but this gives you the option to expand your application in the future.

Comment: thanks for the snippet i think this will work. in my case it was realy an oritentation issue!